# How to configure Tailwind CSS with Vite in a React project?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, tailwind-in-js

I am working on a React project with Vite as the build tool. I want to use Tailwind CSS in my project, but I'm not sure how to configure it with Vite.

I have already installed Tailwind CSS globally using npm install -g tailwindcss. However, when I try to use it in my React components, I get an error saying that the sm: class does not exist.

I have tried to install Tailwind CSS locally using npm install tailwindcss, but I'm not sure how to configure it with Vite.

The specific error is this "The `sm:` class does not exist. If `sm:` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive."
Can anyone guide me on how to configure Tailwind CSS with Vite in my React project? Thank you in advance!

I have tried to update the version of tailwind css in my project and I have remove and reinstall tailwind. I have added responsive variant to the tailwind.config.js file to see if "sm" class work but all in vein.

I want to use custom classes in your React app with Tailwind CSS and Vite, but you are encountering errors.

Comment: Most likely you have a space between `sm:` and some utility (e.g. `sm: bg-blue-500`). Probably IDE formatting issue

Answer (score 1):

you could try installing it as a developer dependency instead try this command

> ```
> npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
> npx tailwindcss init -p
> ```

then follow this [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) to complete configuration

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've added the `responsive` variants to the `variants` option in your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    extend: {
      display: ['responsive'], // Add this line
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

Source: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants